# Regular Expressions with repetitive pattern as well as excluding pattern in one

Tags: python, regex

I would like to get list of .c files using **one line regular expression**
excluding commented out lines (using "python re package").

```
#### a.sh file

A = /x/y/aaa.c /x/y/bbb.c /x/y/ccc.c

#B = /x/y/ddd.c /x/y/eee.c /x/y/fff.c

C = ddd eee fff
.
.
```

Do you have any good solutions using one line regex?

I only made it succeeded **using two regex**
(one for skipping commented out line, and one for grabbing .c files)

Final result would be [aaa.c, bbb.c, ccc.c]

FYI,
following pattern is used for grabbing all .c files:

> pattern: (?:[^/]+.c(?: |$))+

In python:

> re.findall(r'(?:(?:[^/]+.c(?: |$))+)', file.read(), flags=re.MULTILINE)

Comment: There is nothing wrong with reading the file line by line and applying your first regex.  Regex should not be used to parse text files, which is really what you are asking for here.  I can't see an obvious way to use regex to detect if a line is a comment _and_ to extract matches.

Comment: Applying the regex to a single line only also simplifies the pattern you'll have to use with `re.findall`; another benefit of reading line by line.

Comment: Doesn't the Python use famous package beautifulsoup to parse html, xml files?
I think it is based on regex.

Comment: I can't figure out a way around the comment restriction. Too bad Python doesn't support `\G`, else it'd be easy

Comment: @CertainPerformance We _could_ also do it with a variable width lookbehind, but that is a performance killer, error prone, and not really what regex is intended to be doing.